# Best Venue for Embassy-Related Question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/is-there-a-north-korean-interests-section-representation-of-nk-interests-or) was recently migrated to Politics.SE from Law.  In substance, the question asks where North Koreans traveling in the United States can receive consular services.

Since it is a question of diplomatic policy it is definitely on topic here. However, it's been on our site since November (2+ months) without an answer.

Should we migrate it to Travel.SE?  I hate to pass the question off to another Stack (again), but I'm also wondering if experienced world-travelers might know a better way to answer the question than the folks here.

Comment: Since it's ontopic here, SE migration policy would prevent it from being migrated, unfortunately. It'd be easier to migrate if we agreed that it was off-topic (but I agree that it probably would fare better on Travel and would encourage OP to repost there even sans migration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[user4012](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/115/user4012) mentioned this in a comment, but it was strong enough that I think it's the actual answer:

SE migration policy prevents this from being a viable option. Questions should not be migrated just because they are a better fit for another site. Questions should be migrated when they are off-topic on the current site.

In addition to that, it looks like the question is too old to be migrated anyway.

The related meta.SE question is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).